# Proof that $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} \le \frac{1}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification, induction

In a Calculus textbook, I was faced with the following

**Problem:** If $n$ is a natural number with $n \ge 1$, proof that $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} \le \frac{1}{k!}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

The book presented a different solution than the one, I came up with. So maybe mine is wrong. My question now is, if my solution is correct and - more importantly - if not, where I went wrong. Thanks in advance for any comments and advice.

**Solution:** I proof the proposition by induction on $k$. For $k=0$ we have

$$\binom{n}{0}\frac{1}{n^0} = 1 \le \frac{1}{0!},$$

a true statement. Now notice, that if $k \gt n$ we have $\binom{n}{k} = 0$, so the proposition is plainly true. It thus suffices to proof it for $0 \le k \le n$. In this case we have as inductive step

$$\begin{align} \binom{n}{k+1} \frac{1}{n^{k+1}} & = \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^{k}} \cdot \frac{1}{n(k+1)(n-k+1)} \\ & \le \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \frac{1}{n(k+1)(n-k+1)} && \text{by inductive hypothesis} \\ & \le \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{(k+1)!} && \text{since $n \ge 1$ and $n-k+1 \ge 1$}\end{align}$$

as required. $\blacksquare$

As additional comment, I have used the following steps to manipulate the binomial coefficient:

$\binom{n}{k+1} = \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k+1)!} = \frac{n!}{(k+1)k!(n-k+1)(n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)} = \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)}$

Comment: Alternatively, we have $$ \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{\prod_{j=k+1}^n j}{k!} \frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{j=k+1}^n \frac{j}{n} \leq \frac{1}{k!}, $$ where we used that $\frac{j}{n} \leq 1$.

Comment: Yes, this solution was given in my book. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your derivation: $$\binom{n}{k+1} = \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k\color{red}-1)!} \color{blue}{= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{n-k}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{n-k}{k+1}}.$$

So, the final step of your proof should be the following:
\begin{align} 
\binom{n}{k+1} \frac{1}{n^{k+1}} & = \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^{k}} \cdot  \frac{n-k}{n(k+1)} \\ 
& \le \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \frac{n-k}{n(k+1)} && \text{by induction hypothesis} \\ 
& \le \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\frac{n-k}{n} \\
& < \frac{1}{(k+1)!} && \text{since $n-k < n$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative method:
We want to show $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\le n^k$. The LHS is the number of ordered subsets of size $k$ of a set of $n$ elements, the RHS is the number of ordered lists of size $k$ taken from a set of $n$ elements, where its ok if two elements are equal. Clearly the inequality is satisfied with this interpretation.